# How to sort a 2D character array in lexicographical order in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to sort a 2D array in lexicographical order.

Suppose the given 2D array is

```
ebacd
fghij
olmkn
trpqs
xywuv
```

Now after arranging it in lexicographical order the array 2D array will be

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxy
```

Please provide me a logic so that I can get solve this problem. Provided number of rows and columns of the array will be same.

Comment: This is already lexicographically sorted. I don't get what you want

Comment: I want that the array will be horizontally as well as vertically sorted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez" / "do my work for me."

Answer (score 1):

store the first 26 primes.
have a number m = 1
now for each letter in the matrix, multiply m by primes[letter].
Now go through the matrix in order, and divide m by the 1st prime, until it is no longer divisible by 2. (keep adding 'a' ), then keep adding 'b' until m is no longer divisible by 3, etc.

Comment: It's just an answer. qsort() would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

You may be making this problem way harder than it needs to be. You have `5` arrays of `5` characters each. Simply call `qsort` once for each array of `5` chars and sort them, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* integer comparison (adapt for all numeric types) */
int cmpint (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) */
    return (*(char *)a > *(char *)b) - (*(char *)a < *(char *)b);
}

int main (void) {

    char a[][5] = { "ebacd",
                    "fghij",
                    "olmkn",
                    "trpqs",
                    "xywuv"};
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        qsort (a[i], 5, sizeof *a[i], cmpint);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("a[%d] : ", i); 
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            putchar (a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/qsort2dchar
a[0] : abcde
a[1] : fghij
a[2] : klmno
a[3] : pqrst
a[4] : uvwxy
```

---

**Edit -- Per-Comment Horizontal & Vertical Sort**

Let's start with a nasty mixed up array:

```
    char a[][5] = { "ebacd",
                    "trpqs",
                    "olmkn",
                    "fghij",
                    "xywuv"};
```

Now let's add one more `qsort` to sort it all out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* integer comparison (adapt for all numeric types) */
int cmpint (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) */
    return (*(char *)a > *(char *)b) - (*(char *)a < *(char *)b);
}

int main (void) {

    char a[][5] = { "ebacd",
                    "trpqs",
                    "olmkn",
                    "fghij",
                    "xywuv"};
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)          /* sort horizontal */
        qsort (a[i], 5, sizeof *a[i], cmpint);

    qsort (a, 5, sizeof *a, cmpint);    /* sort vertical */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("a[%d] : ", i); 
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            putchar (a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/qsort2dchar
a[0] : abcde
a[1] : fghij
a[2] : klmno
a[3] : pqrst
a[4] : uvwxy
```

---

**Full Lexical Sort if Multiple Occurrences of Characters Possible**

As was pointed out in a comment, if instead of each array of `5` characters containing a unique occurrence of a character, the arrays could contain duplicate character (either within the individual array, or between the rows), then the check of the first character alone is insufficient for the vertical sort.

Adding a second compare that will examine each character and return based on the first mismatch or returning zero if all characters are identical between the rows being compared, you can fully lexigraphically sort the array, regardless of content. The following adds a `cmpnchr` function to accomplish the same.

Consider the input array:

```
    char a[][NCHR] = {  "ebaca",
                        "traqb",
                        "olmkn",
                        "facib",
                        "xywuv"};
```

A full sort would require:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NCHR 5

/* integer comparison (adapt for all numeric types) */
int cmpint (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) */
    return (*(char *)a > *(char *)b) - (*(char *)a < *(char *)b);
}

int cmpnchr (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char  *pa = a,
                *pb = b;
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < NCHR; i++)
        if (pa[i] > pb[i])
            return 1;
        else if (pa[i] < pb[i])
            return -1;

    return 0;
}

int main (void) {

    char a[][NCHR] = {  "ebaca",
                        "traqb",
                        "olmkn",
                        "facib",
                        "xywuv"};
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)          /* sort horizontal */
        qsort (a[i], NCHR, sizeof *a[i], cmpint);

    qsort (a, NCHR, sizeof *a, cmpnchr); /* vertical sort */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("a[%d] : ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < NCHR; j++)
            putchar (a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/qsort2dcharfull
a[0] : aabce
a[1] : abcfi
a[2] : abqrt
a[3] : klmno
a[4] : uvwxy
```

If there are any more additions, they will have to wait until the morning `:)`

Comment: For sake of completeness, if you wish to sort in *descending* order, just rewrite the comparison as `(a < b) - (a > b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two compare function, the one is for horizon-compare, the other one is for vertical-compare:

```
typedef char Row[COLUMNS];
int compareVertical(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(Row *)a)[0] - (*(Row *)b)[0];
}

int compareHorizon(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return *(char *)a - *(char *)b;
}
```

and sort the row first, then sort each row in loop, like this:

```
qsort(arr, ROWS, sizeof(Row), compareVertical);

for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row)
{
    qsort(arr[row], COLUMNS, sizeof(char), compareHorizon);
}
```

Check the complete code here: https://ideone.com/b7rvQh

Comment: Why would you need two compare functions? One works fine. In the vertical case, recall, when you dereference a pointer to an array, you get the first element, e.g. `char *str = "abc"; putchar (*str);` (outputs `a`). Why? `str[0]` is `*(str + 0)` is just `*(str)` which is `*str`.

Comment: Nope, The function parameters are totally different type. `a` in `compareVertical` is a pointer to an array of `COLUMNS` characters; `a` in `compareHorizon` is a pointer to  a character which is the first element of an array of `COLUMNS` characters. Yes, you can cast them to `char*`, but IMHO, it's not clear for this question.

Comment: Now if you consider there can be multiples of any single character, that would not apply. The vertical described was based on the test input, You would have to do a full comparison of the `5` char array elements for a complete vertical sort in that case. I know what you are saying and agree. I'll drop an update after Santa comes in the morning.